# Django-material admin foto de perfil

Tags: python, django, material

Estoy utilizando material-admin en django , y quiero que la imagen de perfil del usuario que se logea en la administracion aparezca en ves de la imagen default, pero no se como hacerlo.
no se si debo configurarlo en el MATERIAL_ADMIN_SITE o como hacerlo